# List Blog Authors

Tags: author

I am trying to set up a “Search by Author” on a blog I am adding to a community website.

I can get the avatars to show up, but instead of a list of avatars, I am getting an avatar for every single entry. I want to remove duplicates and show each author only once.

I understand that the code below will result in it pulling all author's avatars for every.single.post on the site. I have about 10 authors and I want to show their avatars that will link to a list of their blogs.

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="blog" 
    orderby="asc" 
    dynamic="no"
    style="nested"
}
    {if avatar}
        <a href="{site_url}blog/author/{member_id}" class="blogimg">
            <img src="{avatar_url}" class="imgblogauthorbar"/>
        </a>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any advice on how to go about making this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list users, your better option is to use the [Query Module](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/query/index.html). The first sample codes on user guide are all about members.

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT screen_name, email, location FROM exp_members WHERE group_id = '1'"}
        {screen_name}
        {email}
        {location}
{/exp:query}
```

The previous sample, limits the members to who is on group 1, but you can improve it to who is also on [author list](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups_edit.html#include-members-in-publish-page-multi-author-list) and have written entries:

```
SELECT
  screen_name,
  email,
  location
FROM
  exp_members
WHERE
  group_id = '1'
  AND in_authorlist = 'y'
  AND total_entries != 0
ORDER BY 
  last_entry_date
```

You can use `SELECT *` if you want to return all fields on the `exp_members` table.

Comment: `avatar_url` does not work, it pushes out an icon with a question mark.

Comment: I got it figured out `{avatar_filename}` is the correct code. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: @KentPrickett, if the answer is right, please mark it as so. Thanks!